# Delete last line in a RichTextBox in VB .NET

Tags: vb.net

I've been search and I can't found an answer that works, I need to remove (delete) the last line in a `RichTextBox1` in vb.net, I mean remove last line and 'breakline' too, but only the last, no others.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim myList As List(Of String) = richTextBox1.Lines.ToList()
If myList.Count > 0
    myList.RemoveAt(myList.Count - 1)
    richTextBox1.Lines = myList.ToArray()
    richTextBox1.Refresh()
End If
```

Comment: It works but with a little change: List<string> to: List(Of String) thanks :)